# Integrating the product of the Heaviside function with an exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, distribution-theory

This is a question from my textbook in an applied mathematics class:

> On $\mathbb{R}$ with fixed $\alpha >0$, consider the sequences of nonegative continuous functions $$f_k(x) = k^\alpha H(x)xe^{-kx},$$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function.

Part (a) and (b) where to show that $f_k$ converges pointwise (for any $\alpha$) and uniformly (for $\alpha < 1)$ to 0 as $k \rightarrow \infty$, which I have done. Now, in part (c) we have to calculate the integral of the above function from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

I've entered the formula into Wolfram Alpha to see that the final value is $k^{\alpha-2}$, but unfortunately it doesn't show the actual step-by-step calculation.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself when it comes to calculating the integral? What is the problem? $H(x)$? To find a primitive? ...

Comment: The problem is the Heaviside function, I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: Why not check the **definition** of $H$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any function $f$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(x)f(x)\,dx=\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx,
$$
since
$$
H(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x>0\\
0 & x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, your integral equals
$$
k^\alpha\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-kx}\,dx.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Based on mickep's answer, the calculation goes:
$$ k^\alpha \int_0^\infty x e^{-kx}dx = k^\alpha \left[\frac{xe^{-kx}}{-k}+ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}}{k}dx\right] = k^\alpha \left[\frac{-1}{k^2}e^{-kx} dx\right] = \frac{1}{k^{\alpha-2}}.$$

This appears to be different from the Wolfram Alpha answer, did I make a mistake in this calculation?

Comment: The last equality is false.